# Accessing and displaying key-value pairs in Perl from subroutine

Tags: perl

New to Perl. Got syntax errors in accessing key-value pairs from subroutine.

```
 sub displayObj{
    my %obj = shift; //the hash. It is a JSON object after decode_json()
    my $field = shift; //the key we are searching. It is a string. 
    my $serialized = "{}"; //Initialization
    foreach my $key (keys %obj){
    if($key eq $field){
      $serialized = $obj[{$field}];
    }
  }
  print "$serialized\n";
 }
```

It is giving me a compilation error in the `if` block.

I would like to know:

Should I use `%` or `$` in `my %obj`?

How to access the key-value pair (also a JSON object) and assign it to $serialized using $obj?

Comment: _Always_ `use warnings;` and `use strict`.  It would tell you about assigning a single value to a hash.

Comment: @zdim I did in the main block

Comment: But then how do you not get `Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ...` ?

Comment: The shift gives you the first argument in `@_` -- this cannot be a hash. A reference to a hash, perhaps? Assuming that it were a hash, a value for a given key is `$obj{$field}`. If a reference to a hash is indeed passed in, `my $robj = shift` and then `$robj->{$field}`.

Comment: Comments in Perl are written with a `#`, not with `//`. Please show code that at least doesn't have syntax errors.

Comment: Basically, all that `displayObj` is trying to do is: `say $obj{$field}`, right?  You don't need a separate sub for that.

Comment: @zdim: It's not a hash reference, it's a string `"{}"`. Please would you try to cut down on the number if comments you make? You always write a *lot* of comments and it becomes confusing. You have written five comments here -- half of all that have been made -- and all that you have said would be fine in a single comment. Are you aware that you can edit and delete your comments?

Comment: "It is giving me a compilation error in the `if` block." And you didn't think it might be useful to tell us what the syntax error was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to write a subroutine that displays the value of a hash element given its key

But you're missing the basic purpose of hashes: they're *content-addressable*. That means there's no need to iterate through all the keys of a hash comparing them to the string you're looking for, you can write just `$hash{key}` and the search will be done for you very quickly using a *hashing* system (hence the name of the data type). This is just the same as using `$array[$i]` to access an array element directly instead of looping over all of the indices of the array comparing each one to `$i` until you find the element you're looking for

If you're really dealing with objects then you shouldn't be accessing their internal data like this anyway. An object will have *accessor* methods that return the values you're supposed to be using; anything else is part of the internal working of the class and is meant to be private

The syntax error is in this line

```
$serialized = %obj[{$field}]
```

where it looks like you're trying to use *both* a hash key `{...}` and an array index `[...]`. That won't work

You don't show how you're calling your subroutine, but I imagine you're passing a *reference* to a hash, which is a scalar value and must be treated as such inside the subroutine

This program shows a working version of what I think you intended

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $obj = {
    aa => 1,
    cc => 2,
};

displayObj($obj, 'cc');
displayObj($obj, 'bb');

sub displayObj {

    my $obj   = shift; # The hash. It is a JSON object after decode_json()
    my $field = shift; # The key we are searching. It is a string.

    my $serialized = '{}'; # Initialization

    foreach my $key ( keys %$obj ) {
        if ( $key eq $field ) {
            $serialized = $obj->{$field};
        }
    }

    print "$serialized\n";
}
```

#### output

```
2
{}
```

But the loop can be removed altogether as I described, leaving

```
sub displayObj {

    my ($obj, $field) = @_;

    my $serialized = $obj->{$field} // '{}';

    print "$serialized\n";
}
```

which produces exactly the same result. In fact there's little point in creating a subroutine to do this; you can write just

```
print $obj->{bb} // '{}', "\n"
```

with the same effect

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly my first edit before the compile error. But I got error in run time shown as `Can't use string ("{}") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use `. What can be the cause of it?

Comment: @JiajuShen: That is really a separate question so you should post it as one. I had to do a lot of guessing to write this solution, so please include your full program in your question, together with any relevant data files and the desired output. It will help you to read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

I usually do this way:

```
sub displayObj{
   my $objref = shift;
   my %obj = %{$objref}; 

}
```